# Extend ko.observable or access DOM nodes bound to observable

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I'm writing an application using TypeScript and Knockout and have for the last couple of days tried to extend the ko.observable object used in the viewmodel in order to be able to do something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myvalue" />
<button data-bind="click: enable">Enable</button>
<button data-bind="click: disable">Disable</button>
```

Viewmodel:

```
interface KnockoutObservableFunctions<T> {
    enabled(enabled: boolean): void;
}

class MyModel {

    public theValue: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor() {
        ko.observable.fn.enabled = function (enabled: boolean)  {
            // This is not working because I don't have access to the
            // elements, but it should illustrate my intentions.
            $(elements[0]).prop("disabled", !enabled);
        }

        this.theValue = ko.observable("A string");
    }

    public enable(): void {
        this.theValue.enabled(true);
    }
    public disable(): void {
        this.theValue.enabled(false);
    }
}
```

That is, I want to access the DOM node(s) that are bound to an observable in my custom function attached on fn as in the code above. How do I do that? I tried custom bindings but that did not seem like the way to go.

I am aware of the enable/disable bindings in Knockout and that what I ultimately want to do could be by accomplished by using an other observable, i.e. adding an theValueEnabled observable to the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with an extender that adds the `enabled` observable. I'd also like to note that *whenever you want to something with a DOM element, custom bindings **are the only way to go***. :)

Then, you'd have two options:

- Add the `enable` binding to the nested observable: `enable`: myValue.enabled` (You said you didn't want to use this binding, but I think you should and I mention it to give a complete answer)
- Create a binding that combines the `value` and the `enable` binding.

In the example below you can see both bindings. I don't really see the benefits in the second approach, since it obscures the logic and can end up in many different bindings. (E.g. you'll need another one for the `textInput` binding.)

(I don't know typescript, so the example is in plain js. Hope that's okay.)

```js
ko.extenders.enabled = function(target, initialVal) {
  target.enabled = ko.observable(initialVal);
  return target;
}

ko.bindingHandlers.enabledValue = {
  init: function(el, va) {
     ko.applyBindingsToNode(el, { 
       value: va(),
       enable: va().enabled
     });
  }
}

var VM = function() {
  this.myValue = ko.observable("test")
    .extend({
      enabled: true
    });

  this.enable = this.myValue.enabled.bind(null, true);
  this.disable = this.myValue.enabled.bind(null, false);


}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  Two bindings:
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: myValue, 
                                enable: myValue.enabled" />
</div>

<div>
  One binding:
  <input type="text" data-bind="enabledValue: myValue" />
</div>
<button data-bind="click: enable">Enable</button>
<button data-bind="click: disable">Disable</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.If I wanted to control the readonly attribute instead for which there is no binding in Knockout, would adding a subscription to that observable in the extender be a good solution?

Comment: You can use the `attr` binding to change any attribute. I.e.: `attr: { readonly: myValue.enabled }`